# How do I get the value of text inside of the file using Qt?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt

The data of my `file.txt` is as below:

```
Student_ID=0001
Student_Name=joseph
Student_GradeLevel=2
```

How do I get the value, let say I want to get the `Student_ID` using Qt.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use Qt classes or can you use `std::ifstream`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I need to use Qt classes, then what should I do? thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this function, it can be used to **find any value you want in your input file**, where all lines are in the format you've posted above (`key=value`). If the key is not found, it returns an empty `QString()` object.

```
QString findValueInFile(QString key, QString filename) {
    QFile file(filename);

    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QTextStream txtStr(&file);
        QStringList fileContent = txtStr.readAll().split('\n');

        for(auto &&line : fileContent) {
            if(line.contains(key)) return line.split(QChar('='))[1];
        }

        file.close();
    }

 return QString(); // not found
}
```

Now you call it somewhere, e.g.:

```
qDebug() << findValueInFile("Student_ID", "file.txt");
qDebug() << findValueInFile("Student_Name", "file.txt");
```

This function can be easily modified if you replace your `=` sign with other delimiter e.g. `=>` or sth else. However for `key=value` format there is a special `QSettings` class (mentioned by *sebastian*) that can allow you to **read those values even easier**:

```
QSettings file("file.txt", QSettings::IniFormat);
qDebug() << file.value("Student_Name").toString(); // et voila!
```

Comment: Is a `not stream,atEnd()` loop any more idiomatic in Qt than in other file interfaces? Usually these are an anti-pattern, because they turn into infinite loops when the stream is in an error state, or because they have an extraneous iteration at the end.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I doubt that. I agree there are safier way to read files like that. In this case it'd be even better to `.readAll()` whole file and iterate through splitted lines, instead of reading them from stream like that.

Comment: @Noooobz2016, simplified the first option and made it a bit safer for you (thanks, Sebastian Redl).

Comment: Thanks that helped

Answer (score 0):

You can probably also use `QSettings`, as they are able to read ini files.
There are some caveats though regarding backslashes which might be important to you (though they aren't for the example you posted): http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#Format-enum

```
QSettings iniFile("myfile.txt", QSettings::IniFormat);
// now get the values by their key
auto studentId = iniFile.value("Student_ID").toString().toInt();
```

I'm more of a `PyQt` user, so: apologies if I got some C++ specifics wrong...